# How do you add spaces in front of 'y' integers in a nested loop?

Tags: python-3.7

```
for x in range(1, 4):
    print(x)
    for y in range(5, 10):
        print(y)
```

I tried adding "   " + in front of y within print. Essentially,

```
print("  " + y)
```

I tried creating a string w that equals "   " to add in front of y. Essentially,

```
w = "  "
print(w + y)
```

I'd like the output to look like:

```
1
  5
  6
2
  5
  6
3
  5
  6
```

I'm exploring .join() at the moment to see if this method can provide a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for x in range(1, 4):

```
print(x)
```

for y in range(5, 10):

```
    w = "  "
    print(w + str(y)) or print(" " + str(y))
```

output:

1

```
5


6
```

2

```
 5


 6
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like a simple solution by adding the str function in front of y.

Answer (score 0):

Python string formatting is easy and clean in this case. You can see https://pyformat.info/ for a quick introduction.

Example with the most recent `format` function:

```py
for x in range(1, 4):
     print("{:d}".format(x))
     for y in range(5, 10):
         print("{:>3d}".format(y))
```

Short explanation:

- `{:d}`: format the argument as a digit
- `{:>3d}`: align right, make the string 3 characters long and format the argument as a digit